# Implicit in Scala 'for' enumerator?

Tags: scala, implicit

How can you make a variable introduced in a `for` statement (an Enumerator, as it's called in the spec) implicit?

Here's an example of what I'd *like* to write:

```
for (implicit genNum: GenNum <- NumGens(200)) {
  val explicitArg = // . . .
  funcWithImplicitGenNum(explicitArg)  // <-- gen passed implicitly here
}
```

where `funcWithImplicitGenNum` is declared like this:

```
def funcWithImplicitGenNum(explicitArg: Whatever)(implicit gen: GenNum) = ???
```

If I understand the spec correctly, it doesn't allow a `for`'s Enumerator to be implicit, so I have to do this:

```
for (g <- NumGens(200)) {
  implicit val genNum: GenNum = g
  val explicitArg = // . . .
  funcWithImplicitGenNum(explicitArg)  // <-- gen passed implicitly here
}
```

This workaround is not the end of the world, but it bothers me. In my actual program, I pass several variables implicitly all over the place, which provide the overall context in which something is happening. Scala's implicits have been wonderful for this: they greatly reduce the amount of clutter in the code, yet functions deep in the call stack have access to that contextual information. The only exception is `for` loops: I have to do this clumsy trick of defining a `val` that equals the enumeration variable.

Is there a way to pass `genNum` implicitly? Or, if not, do you know of a reason why I should be glad that the `for` statement doesn't allow its Enumerator to be made implicit? (Often, if you know the rationale for a language feature, you see better how to "go with the grain" of the language.)

---

Here's a little more background, if it helps. I'm writing a genetic algorithm that uses a variety of mutation operators. A mutation operator shouldn't know which generation it's being called for. But I'm also collecting data about how the mutations perform in different generations. The data-collection code *does* need to know which generation it is, plus a few other things. So, I pass the variables that pertain to mutation explicitly, and the variables needed for data collection implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently possible.  [Here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2823) is the ticket for the relevant feature request.  There, Martin Odersky writes:

> The problem I see is the interaction with many other things. The [implicit variable]
>   might be a pattern – should the implicit then apply to all its
>   variables? Then, the translation of generators in for expressions is
>   quite involved. We'd have to specify how implicits are taken into
>   account.

As a workaround, you can put the `implicit` loop in a wrapping `map` or `flatMap` (which, of course, isn't ideal):

```
class Foo

object FooRunner {
    val foos = List(new Foo, new Foo, new Foo)
    def runFoo(i: Int)(implicit foo: Foo) = println(s"Foo ran $i")

    def runFoos = foos.map { implicit foo =>
        for(i <- (1 to 100)) {
            runFoo(i) //implicit works here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the implicit argument explicitly like so:

```
for (val genNum <- NumGens(200)) {
  val explicitArg = // . . .
  funcWithImplicitGenNum(explicitArg)(genNum)  // <-- gen passed explictly here
}
```

As for the why question, I do not have evidence but consider the scope implications this will have say you used `val i` in a piece of implicit for loop and another programmer in a different file is trying to do a simple for loop with variable name. 
Voodoo will ensue

Although I would actually map (or foreach depending on function side effects)

```
val result = NumGens(200).map{ implicit i =>
val explicitArg = ??
funcWithImplicitGenNum(explicitArg)
}
```

Comment: Passing the variable explicitly is certainly the fallback position. I'm hoping to avoid it, though, because then I'll have to add it everywhere inside the loop where the implicits get passed (in my actual program there are several implicits). Basically, this would be giving up on implicits--not the end of the world, but disappointing.

Comment: Hmm, calling `.map` or `.foreach` might be just the solution. If I understand things correctly, your example could go `.map { implicit genNum i => ... }`. Is that right?

Comment: Regarding scope, I think I have that under control, because the type of each implicit val ensures that it gets passed exactly where it's needed, regardless of the val's name. In fact, for my purposes the val [doesn't even need a name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28134913/1393162), since its type says everything that both I and the compiler need to know about it. Giving the variable a name only creates the possibility of undesired shadowing.